# Orthonormal basis implies that the inner product equals the coordinate vectors under the basis multipled together

Tags: linear-algebra

If $V$ is a finite-dimensional product space, and $B$ is a basis for $V$, then $B$ is orthonormal iff $\langle f,g \rangle=[f]_B\cdot [g]_B$.

How can we prove this result in both directions (i.e. one where we assume $B$ is orthonormal and another where we assume $\langle f,g \rangle=[f]_B\cdot [g]_B$)? I don't understand how being orthonormal relates to a specific inner product.

Answer (score 0):

Let $B = \{b_1,...b_n\}$ be an orthonormal basis. Write $f$ as $\sum_{i=1}^n f_i b_i$ and $g$ as $\sum_{j=1}^n g_j b_j$. Now, take the inner product $\langle f,g \rangle=\langle \sum_{i=1}^n f_i b_i, \sum_{j=1}^n g_j b_j \rangle$ and expand it out by linearity to obtain $\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n f_ig_j \langle b_i, b_j \rangle$. By orthonormality, $\langle b_i, b_j \rangle = \delta_{ij}$, and our sum becomes $\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n f_ig_j \delta_{ij} = \sum_{i=1}^n f_ig_i = [f]_B\cdot [g]_B$.

Going the other direction, suppose $B$ is a basis such that $\langle f,g \rangle = [f]_B\cdot [g]_B$. Then $\langle b_i,b_j \rangle$ can clearly be seen to equal $\delta_{ij}$ and the basis is orthonormal.